# Is it possible for an application to fetch a specific location string from Google Maps?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android application that uses the location service. I want to get an address of specific place to my application, now I don't want to develop an another activity for fetching string . So I want to use an existing maps app to get location string. So could anyone please help me with some idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you just need a geocoding API, like google do https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

But did you search on google first ?

Comment: Yes, I did searched for the problem of mine. What I need is that, suppose you are developing an application which uses some kind of location thing and you need to get an exact location of any place from the readily available google maps application on your device. For this problem I need to separately develop an map activity to serve my problem , instead of that is it possible to use implicit intent to jump to Google maps application and get the location from there.